# CPT archive admin menu label

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type-archives

I'm using the following code in order to make a cpt:

```
function midas_team_post() {
  register_post_type( 'midas-team',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
          'name' => 'تیم میداس',
          'singular_name' => 'تیم میداس',
          'add_new' => 'افزودن ورزشکار',
          'add_new_item' => 'افزودن ورزشکار',
          'edit_item' => 'ویرایش ورزشکار',
          'archives'  => 'اعضا'
      ),
      'rewrite' => array ( 'slug' => __( 'members' ) ) ,
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' =>  true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups',
      'supports'  => array( 'title', 'thumbnail' ),
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'midas_team_post' );
```

So when I set `has_archive` to true in admin menu a sub menu will be created with name like this: `{cpt_name} Archive` and the problem is that I want to remove that "Archive" form the cpt sub-menu and make it something like this: `All {cpt_name}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [`register_post_type()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/), which links to [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_labels/), you'll see all the labels that you can set. There are more than the 6 you have defined. I believe `all_items` is the one you're talking about.

> - `name` – General name for the post type, usually plural. The same and overridden by `$post_type_object->label`. Default is ‘Posts’ /
>     ‘Pages’.
> - `singular_name` – Name for one object of this post type.
>     Default is ‘Post’ / ‘Page’.
> - `add_new` – Default is ‘Add New’ for both hierarchical and non-hierarchical types. When internationalizing this string, please
>     use a gettext context matching your post type. Example: `_x( 'Add New',  'product', 'textdomain' );`.
> - `add_new_item` – Label for adding a new singular item. Default is ‘Add New Post’ / ‘Add New Page’.
> - `edit_item` – Label for editing a singular item. Default is ‘Edit Post’ / ‘Edit Page’.
> - `new_item` – Label for the new item page title. Default is ‘New Post’ / ‘New Page’.
> - `view_item` – Label for viewing a singular item. Default is ‘View Post’ / ‘View Page’.
> - `view_items` – Label for viewing post type archives. Default is ‘View Posts’ / ‘View Pages’.
> - `search_items` – Label for searching plural items. Default is ‘Search Posts’ / ‘Search Pages’.
> - `not_found` – Label used when no items are found. Default is ‘No posts found’ / ‘No pages found’.
> - `not_found_in_trash` – Label used when no items are in the trash. Default is ‘No posts found in Trash’ / ‘No pages found in Trash’.
> - `parent_item_colon` – Label used to prefix parents of hierarchical
>     items. Not used on non-hierarchical post types. Default is ‘Parent
>     Page:’.
> - `all_items` – Label to signify all items in a submenu link. Default is ‘All Posts’ / ‘All Pages’.
> - `archives` – Label for archives in nav menus. Default is ‘Post Archives’ / ‘Page Archives’.
> - `attributes` – Label for the attributes meta box. Default is ‘Post Attributes’ / ‘Page Attributes’.
> - `insert_into_item` – Label for the media frame button. Default is ‘Insert into post’ / ‘Insert into page’.
> - `uploaded_to_this_item` – Label for the media frame filter. Default is ‘Uploaded to this post’ / ‘Uploaded to this page’.
> - `featured_image` – Label for the Featured Image meta box title. Default is ‘Featured Image’.
> - `set_featured_image` – Label for setting the featured image. Default is ‘Set featured image’.
> - `remove_featured_image` – Label for removing the featured image. Default is ‘Remove featured image’.
> - `use_featured_image` – Label in the media frame for using a featured image. Default is ‘Use as featured image’.
> - `menu_name` – Label for the menu name. Default is the same as `name`.
> - `filter_items_list` – Label for the table views hidden heading. Default is ‘Filter posts list’ / ‘Filter pages list’.
> - `items_list_navigation` – Label for the table pagination hidden heading.
>     Default is ‘Posts list navigation’ / ‘Pages list navigation’.
> - `items_list` – Label for the table hidden heading. Default is ‘Posts list’ / ‘Pages list’.

If you're seeing any other labels involving your post type name that aren't listed here then they are likely generated by your theme or a plugin that's using one of these labels in combination with its own text. How to resolve this would depend on that plugin and how it works. You will need to check its documentation or contact its developer.

Comment: Thank u for answering but it's not what I meant... Look at this picture where I've a cpt and a sub-menu which is `{cpt_name} Archive`. I want to remove that `Archive`. [https://midass.club/archive.png](https://midass.club/archive.png) and also when I set `has_archive` to false it will be gone and it have a URL like this: `edit.php?post_type=midas-team&page=midas-team-archive`

Comment: As you can see then, that item is not in the list. This implies to me that you are using a plugin that adds this option to post type menus. You would need to check with it’s developer if it’s possible to hangs this.

Comment: You were right I've disabled one of my plugins and it's gone now, thankss...would you mind to add this to your answer so I can check it as accepted answer

Comment: I've updated my answer.